# User creates an account with Apple sign-in then deletes their account on my app, they can't create a new account

Tags: javascript, apple-sign-in

When a user signs up with Apple then deletes their account on my app's edit profile page, then tries again to create an account again with apple sign in, they are given a 500 error page.

The only way to fix this is to delete the website from the AppleID dashboard (Manage websites & apps...).

This is because Apple already thinks the account was created so it won't send the email or full name again to my app.

I can't find anything in the documentation to solve this. Has anyone solved this issue, without telling users they need to delete my app from their list of Apps on their AppleID dashboard.

Comment: You've self documented the problem in your question. When an end user "authorizes" and app to access their account, a UID is created that binds that _instance_ of the app to the user account. Then, in order to allow cross platform access, Apple shares that UID between devices (think keychain). Now all devices have a UID that binds your app to the UID. So, "_When a user signs up with Apple then deletes their account on my app's edit profile page_" your app deletes the profile, but Apple has not deleted the UID used by Apple that is associated with that app. You've discovered the only way...

Comment: @randycasburn Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I was hoping to find some documentation on this but no luck.

Comment: This describes the Apple end of things for a service that you have chosen as a user experience. So this document is from the end user's perspective: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210426#stopusingappleid

Comment: Point being, you'll need to refer to that doc in your instructions about "_completely_ deleting their account from your app"

Comment: Thank you @RandyCasburn